# How to install Hadoop in Kubernetes via Helm Chart?

Tags: hadoop, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy Hadoop using Helm Chart in K8s. Not sure what are the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

All the official stalbe chart from helm can be found in this [github repository](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable). So, in order to install Hadoop you can use [stable/hadoop](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/hadoop) chart:

You only have to execute:

```
helm install --name hadoop $(stable/hadoop/tools/calc_resources.sh 50) stable/hadoop
```

And it will be running.

As it is explained in the `README.md` of the chart, the only requirement is than you need at least 2GB of free memory per NodeManager pod. If your cluster isn't large enough, not all pods will be scheduled.

Comment: These charts are now deprecated.  There seems to be no official chart at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are more solutions I found:

- (Active maintained as of today 3/21/2023) Stackable Operator for Apache Hadoop: https://github.com/stackabletech/hdfs-operator

  - Guide: https://docs.stackable.tech/home/stable/hdfs/getting_started/index.html
- (Not active maintained) https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable
- (Not active maintained) HDFS on Kubernetes: https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/kubernetes-HDFS
- (Not active maintained) https://github.com/Gradiant/bigdata-charts/tree/master/charts/hdfs

*Disclosure: I am not associated with Stackable.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "Hadoop" here.

Hadoop consists of many components. Need Storage? Use [Apache Ozone](https://ozone.apache.org/), which was a subproject of Hadoop, purpose-built for cloud-native, Kubernetes solutions.

Need YARN? Why? You shouldn't really be using Mapreduce. Spark and Flink, for example, can deploy direct to Kubernetes.

*Zookeeper* charts do exist. But if you use the above options, you don't need to run any NameNode in HA mode. If you use Ozone, you don't need Datanodes.